# Reasons for lack of output of git fetch (zsh console)?

Tags: git, zsh, git-fetch

I've encountered a problem with git recently. For one of my repositories it does not show any output for `git fetch` any more.

All the repositories are stored on the same [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html) server.

See what happens now in my console:

```
# jul is the user
# pushing some work on master
jul@jul-Precision-M4800 ~/workspace/repo-name (git)-[local_branch] % git push origin local_branch:master
Counting objects: 47, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 777 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
To gitolite:repo-name
   9bd0d8e..308fe47  local_branch -> master

# alright, later (I know there are changes): fetch a fresh(!) master
jul@jul-Precision-M4800 ~/workspace/repo-name (git)-[local_branch] % git fetch
jul@jul-Precision-M4800 ~/workspace/repo-name (git)-[local_branch] % git fetch --all
Fetching origin

# no output!!
# but there are updates (2 fresh commits):

jul@jul-Precision-M4800 ~/workspace/repo-name (git)-[local_branch] % git log --oneline local_branch..origin/master
acde85f Merge branch 'master' of gitolite:repo-name
3b1eb49 any commit message
jul@jul-Precision-M4800 ~/workspace/repo-name (git)-[local_branch] %
```

---

Did anybody see this, too? Which additional informations could be helpful? What are the possible reasons and solutions? Note, that the same works perfectly for the other repositories on this server.

---

**[Edit:]**
After deleting all remote tracking branches the situation has not changed.

Comment: Can you try git fetch --verbose ?

Comment: under the assumption there is an existing master in your local repository, I'd expect the push to update your local `refs/origin/master`, which would make an output from fetch incorrect behaviour.

Comment: @edi9999 OK, even `git fetch --verbose` says `= [up to date] master -> origin/master`, quoting the entry for the master branch only. But it has fetched one commit: `git log --oneline current_branch..origin/master` gives me: `af3df68 small refactorings`. My current_branch was up to date with origin/master before fetching.
I don't quite understand, why git fetch isn't telling me, that the origin/master has been updated. I don't have a local master branch yet and my current_branch has no remote tracking branch. Any suggestions, what I'm misunderstanding here?